# Jacobian and Hessian of $f(x) = \langle x, Ax \rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

A is a $\Re^{n \times n}$ Matrix.
f is a function from $\Re^n$ to $\Re$ with $f(x) = \langle x, Ax \rangle$.
How can I determine the gradient and hessian of this Matrix at point x?

Comment: (1) You are not finding the gradient or Hessian "of this matrix," you are finding them of the scalar function $f(x)$. (2) Try it for $n=2$ and $A=[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}]$.

Comment: While knowing how to manipulate higher-dimensional expressions is useful, you _still can just write $f(x)$ in terms of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and the entries $A_{ij}$ of $A$_.

Comment: Hint: Write $\mathbf x = (x_1 \ , \ \dots \ ,\ x_N).$ You need to explicitly write out $f$ in terms of $x_1 \ , \ \dots \ , x_N$ and compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_m \partial x_n}$ for all $1 \le m,n \le N.$ How do you construct the Jacobian matrix (in this case gradient) and the Hessian matrix of $f$ based on the partial derivatives ?